# Setup passwort for Ethereum address transfers?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Is it possible to setup password for Ethereum address for security reason, so that any time i would like to transfer found i need to include transfer password? On web3 or any other script,...? So that would mean even if my privet key or seed-phrase words get "hacked" password will be needed to transfer founds.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If your seed phrase gets compromised, e.g. by someone taking a photo of the physical paper where you wrote it down, it is game over and no password will save you.

Comment: Only way how to work around this would be to use a multi-signature wallet.

Comment: Also you can just ensure you do not get hacked

Comment: It is true that there are many ways to minimize the risk. Combining these and a multisig probably provides the most security ... but I would also say that there is no 100% security, as humans are involved :D